# Update Panel Triggering Other Update Panel Progress Indicator?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have two update panels on one page, and both with UpdateProgress controls on - But whichever one I click... It triggers BOTH update progress controls??  Anyway to stop this so only the updateprogress triggers on the panel the button has been clicked on.

Comment: Did you set both UpdateProgress Control's AssociatedUpdatePanelID's ?

Comment: DOH! Thank you I had completely missed that!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the UpdateMode property on each UpdatePanel to Conditional might help.

Updatemode="Conditional"